# After Transaction error also data getting saved

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and i am using code like

```
$this->db->trans_start(); 
some 5 mysql inserts and 
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

I am getting error like `DB Transaction Failure` on 5th query i.e. some duplicate entry error. But still all my 1st 4 querys are executed. Should not it roll back ?

Answer (score 0):

use `"Strict Mode"` for your transaction. If will automatically roll back other query if one of the query fails. click [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html) to see details. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you could run transactions manually as follows:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```